# Easiest way to compute a point inside of two arcs (doughnut segment)

Tags: math, svg

I need a general solution. Here is a specific example. I have an SVG path defined by `d="M239.9,254.0A113.7,113.7,0,0,0,322.5,289.7L322.4,341.9A166,166,0,0,1,201.8,289.9Z"`

Or using `M x0 y0 A r1 r2 0 larc sweep x1 y1 L x2 y2 A r3 r4 0 larc sweep x3 y3`

```
x0=239.9 y0=254.0 
x1=322.5 y1=289.7
```

Are the end points of the inner arc and since r1=r2=113.7 it is a circle. Since its larc=0 the angle between the two points is less than 180 degrees. Sweep=0 means that the arc is drawn counterclockwise.

```
x2=322.4 y2=341.9 
x3=201.8 y3=289.9
```

Are the end points of the outer arc and since r3=r4=166 it is also a circle. Since its larc=0 the angle between the two points is less than 180 degrees. Sweep=1 means that arc is drawn clockwise.

I could compute the midpoint of two of the endpoints e.g. 
`xm=(x3+x2)/2 ym=(y3+x2)/2` but any rounding error could put the point outside the doughnut segment.

I know how to compute the midpoints of each arc and I could compute the midpoint between the two arc midpoints but that is a lot of equations. Is there a simpler way? I just need a point inside the doughnut. Remember that larc (large-arc) could = 1 so angles could be greater than 180.

Comment: Computation for the midpoint of an arc can be found here.  See Christian Blatter's answer.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/how-to-find-center-of-an-arc-given-start-point-end-point-radius-and-arc-direc

Comment: Computing the mid-point of an arc is more complicated then I had thought.  So a better link than the above is http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54365.html